# Escape (end) in terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, command

When I call methods where the output length is longer than the length of the terminal window, a highlighted (END) is returned at the end of the output (see picture). How can I escape from this? [image: Mac terminal end]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Type 'q' to escape the (end) and return to what you were doing before

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy i am search this for long time.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you are running in a script do an "echo q" before piping the command.
For example:
echo q | node --version